# Parsing through multiple result pages

Tags: php, parsing, xpath

I am trying to parse a website to obtain aeronautical information. Here is the link to the website

[NOTAMS](http://www.aipchile.gob.cl/notam?notam_filters%5Bfir%5D=&notam_filters%5Bserie%5D%5Btext%5D=&notam_filters%5Btipo%5D=&notam_filters%5Bcodigo%5D%5Btext%5D=QFALC&notam_filters%5Btransito%5D%5Btext%5D=&notam_filters%5Bobjetivo%5D%5Btext%5D=&notam_filters%5Balcance%5D%5Btext%5D=&notam_filters%5Btexto%5D%5Btext%5D=&filter=1&boton=Filtrar)

The problem is the script shows only the first 20 entries ( a single pages worth) from the the entire result set (38) and I am unable to iterate through others pages, as the next url doesn't have any page information. here is my code:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTMLFile($url);


$selector = new DOMXPath($DOM);
$elements = $selector->query('//td[@headers="notam"]'); 


if (!is_null($elements)) {
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo "<br/>";//[". $element->nodeName. "]";
    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
       $display = $node->nodeValue;
    if($display <> NULL){
            echo $node->nodeValue. "<br>";
    }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really see the problem with iterating in the collection... If you add page=x in the query string, it will definitely work. Could you give us some more details?

[Example page 1](http://www.aipchile.gob.cl/notam?page=1&notam_filters%5Bfir%5D=&notam_filters%5Bserie%5D%5Btext%5D=&notam_filters%5Btipo%5D=&notam_filters%5Bcodigo%5D%5Btext%5D=QFALC&notam_filters%5Btransito%5D%5Btext%5D=&notam_filters%5Bobjetivo%5D%5Btext%5D=&notam_filters%5Balcance%5D%5Btext%5D=&notam_filters%5Btexto%5D%5Btext%5D=&filter=1&boton=Filtrar)
[Example page 2](http://www.aipchile.gob.cl/notam?page=2&notam_filters%5Bfir%5D=&notam_filters%5Bserie%5D%5Btext%5D=&notam_filters%5Btipo%5D=&notam_filters%5Bcodigo%5D%5Btext%5D=QFALC&notam_filters%5Btransito%5D%5Btext%5D=&notam_filters%5Bobjetivo%5D%5Btext%5D=&notam_filters%5Balcance%5D%5Btext%5D=&notam_filters%5Btexto%5D%5Btext%5D=&filter=1&boton=Filtrar) (with ...?page=2..., the rest of the url does not change)

As seen in example 1, you can use page=1 in your first url, which makes your code even easier.

Depending on your service requirements, I would also consider using [Kimonolabs website to api service](https://www.kimonolabs.com/), so you would end up querying a simple json api, using a library such as [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) to make your code maintainable and easy to read.

Comment: Thanks!!! as always the answer was easier than I thought... and thanks for the kimono tip... it seems a great tool...